# Fisher Yates Shuffle on a Cards List

Tags: c#, shuffle

I'm trying to do the Fisher Yates shuffle on a list of Cards.  I've scoured forums and the only implementation of Fisher Yates is with normal int arrays like below

```
for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
  int j = random.Next(i + 1);
  int temp = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;
}
```

Which makes sense just fine, my trouble is I don't really see how to convert that logic to the way I have things, any help in accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated.  Relevant code below:

```
public struct Card : IComparable<Card>
{
  public Rank Rank { get; private set; }
  public Suit Suit { get; private set; }

  public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) : this()
  {
    Rank = rank;
    Suit = suit;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format("{0:x} {1}", (char) Suit, Rank);
  }
}
public enum Suit { Spades = 9824, Clubs = 9827, Hearts = 9829, Diamonds = 9830 }
public enum Rank { Ace, Deuce, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King }

public class Deck
{
  public List<Card> Cards { get; private set; }

  public Deck()
  {
    foreach (Rank rank in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Rank)))
    {
      foreach (Suit suit in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Suit)))
      {
        Card card = new Card(rank, suit);
        Cards.Add(card);
      }
    }
  }
  public Deck(List<Card> cardDeck)
  {
    Cards = cardDeck;
  }
  public void Shuffle()
  {  //???? I don't know how I would apply the Fisher Yates logic to here
     //since all other programs just use normal int arrays
  . . .
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: There are a few programming errors in your code, you never initialize `Cards` and you do not implement `IComparable<Card>`

Comment: I was only posting the relevant code to the Shuffle issue, both of those are addressed in other parts.

Answer (score 5):

Surely the logic is exactly the same? The only different is that you are reading a `Card` from your collection rather than an `int`, i.e.

```
for (int i = Cards.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    int j = random.Next(i + 1);
    Card temp = Cards[i]; // Notice the change on this line
    Cards[i] = Cards[j];
    Cards[j] = temp;
}
```

After fixing up the programming errors mentioned in the comment, this implementation seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Having actually done this before (albeit using my own shuffle, still based on ints), I would do this:

1. Add a constructor to the card class that takes an `int`. Its pretty easy to map the 52 cards of a deck to the numbers 0-51, so I'll leave that to you. **Note**: This becomes a *lot* easier if you map the suits to 0-3, instead of the seemingly random numbers you have chosen.
2. Create a starting "deck" using a for loop to generate all 52 cards.
3. Run the shuffle on this created list.

Comment: The seemingly random numbers are the hex numbers so the Suits actually display an actual character for the suit.

Comment: @user3066571 Alright. It would work either way. As the other answer said, you could actually do it already since you already generate the deck.