# Generation of random capital letters in C# while checking to generate only one pair from each

Tags: c#, random, generator

Hi I'm trying to code basic console Pexeso game in C#. And I'm wondering how to generate one and only one pair of capital letters.

So far my code can genereate string with random capital letters but I don't know how to control it to generate only two and only two from each one.

```
        string chars = "AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLL";
        var stringChars = new char[24];
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
        {
            stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
        }

        string finalString = new String(stringChars);

        Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can concatenate 2 random elements from `char[]` and save it to 'stringChars[]'. Datatype of `stringChar[]` should be `string[]` not `char[]`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+fisher+yates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start off well by defining all items you want in your final sequence.

What you want to do next is not take items from that list (in a way that you can take them more than once) as you do now, instead you actually want to *shuffle* your list.

Imagine your letters are playing cards, and you take two full sets. You shuffle them, and you have a sequence of playing cards, in which every card appears exactly twice.

To shuffle your set of letters, or any given sequence, you can use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943286/fisher-yates-shuffle-on-a-cards-list).

Something like this should do the trick:

```
for (int i = chars.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    char j = random.Next(i + 1);
    int temp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[j];
    chars[j] = temp;
}
```

Now your `finalString` is no longer needed: the result you want is in your `chars` array.

Answer (score 0):

One of the trivial solutions for your problem is using LINQ's method `OrderBy` with a random number:

```
string chars = "AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLL";

Random random = new Random();
var shuffled = chars.OrderBy(c => random.Next(chars.Length));

string finalString = new string(shuffled.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

Sometimes you may see people using `Guid` instead of random numbers:

```
string chars = "AABBCCDDEEFFGGHHIIJJKKLL";

var shuffled = chars.OrderBy(c => Guid.NewGuid());

string finalString = new string(shuffled.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

Comment: Guids are not random - they are unique. You can only rely on that property.